# array value not showing length, but when i open so the element is exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

array value not showing length, but when i open so the element is exist. but length and some other functions of array not working...
"""const getingLikedNft = async () => {
setMyNftLoading(true);
const res = await axios.get(`${BACKEND_URL}views_and_likes`);
console.log("resshan", res);
// let likedNft = [];
var myLikedNft = new Array();

```
res?.data.forEach((element) => {
  // console.log("xshan", element);
  if (element?.likedAccounts.length > 0) {
    element?.likedAccounts.forEach(async (elem) => {
      if (elem?.toLowerCase() == user?.address?.toLowerCase()) {
        console.log("resshan_elem", element);
        try {
          let res = await axios.post(`${BACKEND_URL}single-nft`, {
            tokenId: element.tokenId,
            tokenAddr: element.tokenAddr,
          });
          console.log("reslikedNFT", res.data);
          // const uri = await contracts?.closedSeaNft?.methods
          //   .tokenURI(element.tokenId)
          //   .call();
          // const res = await axios.get(uri);
          var nftData = {
            description: res?.data?.metadata?.description,
            image: res?.data?.metadata?.imageUrl,
            title: res?.data?.metadata?.name,
            url: `/asset/${res?.data?.tokenAddr}/${res?.data?.tokenId}`,
          };
          console.log("reslikedN22FT2324232", Array.prototype.nftData);
          myLikedNft = [...myLikedNft, nftData];
          // myLikedNft.push({
          //   description: nftData.description,
          //   image: nftData.imageUrl,
          //   title: nftData.name,
          //   url: `/asset/${res?.data?.tokenAddr}/${res?.data?.tokenId}`,
          // });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("element?.likedAccounts [err]", err);
        }
        // likedNft.push(element);
        // console.log("elem", elem);
      }
    });
  }
});
console.log("reslikedNFT2321312341312dasd", myLikedNft);
setMyLikesCollection(myLikedNft);
setTimeout(() => {
  setMyNftLoading(false);
}, 2000);
```

};"""

you can see it is showing empty array.
[image]

but when i open this so the element is exists.

[image]

how can i solve this kindly help...

Answer (score 0):

You are making an async call for every iteration in the `forEach` loop. But the execution of the `forEach` will finish before you get a response for each of your async calls.

When you print the `myLikedNft` to the console, at the time of printing, the array has no data, because the async calls have not resolved. But when you expand them in the console, it gives you the latest value of the expression.